# how to programmatically modify the FPS of a video

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, video-processing

I'm using OpenCV's `cv::VideoCapture` class to read frames from videos.

My guess is I could drop every 2nd frame to go from 30 FPS to 15 FPS, or I could drop every 3rd frame to go from 30 FPS to 20 FPS, etc.

...but I suspect this is not the right way to do it.  Isn't there some sort of interpolation or re-interpretation of frames that needs to happen to *smoothly* modify the FPS?

Assuming there is, what would this be called so I can search for it?  I believe projects like VLC can re-encode videos to use a different FPS, but I'm more curious to know about how to programmatically do this work in C++ with OpenCV.

Comment: I would call that resampling, you're changing the period between samples of the signal.

Comment: I suspect that dropping frames would generally produce better results. Interpolation is going to produce blurred results around the edges of anything in motion. A lower frame rate is going to be choppy but that still seems like it would be less jarring to the viewer.